# How to know whether a running application has exited and based on that do something in C?

Tags: c

How do i know that a process [not called by c] has exited and based on that do something in C?

For eg. there is a running application , say notepad. I create an application to delete the text file created by it. I cannot do that while it is open . So how do I know when notepad exits and based on that take a decision in C.,.,

Comment: You can check the OS process list to find if the application has exited. You can check the OS to find if the file is "busy". You can... try your hands at some simpler programming exercise, since you're trying swimming in waters that are too deep for you, apparently. ;)

Comment: Not sure why this deserves a close vote, it's a reasonable question.

Comment: @abligh: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." -- I could also have voted for "unclear", "too broad" or "not a real question". I'm happy the OP found an answer to his liking, but personally I wouldn't have thought a POSIX API answer would fit his Windows (Notepad) question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the PID of the process, you can use the `kill()` function. Sending signal 0 to the process is guaranteed *not* to kill it, but merely to report on whether it is running.

If you don't know the PID of the process, there is often a pidfile on disk for the process concerned (e.g. `/var/run/processname.pid`) - look at the file that starts it for more information. If this PID file is not there, the process should not be running. If it is there, the file contains (as text) the PID of the process, which you can check using the method above.

If you do not know the PID of the process and it does not have a PID file, then you will have to walk `/proc`, or shell out to `pgrep` or similar. Avoid this if possible.